# something wrong with the output of sample code

Tags: python-3.x

```
mystring= 'Fred enters the swamp and picks up %s to eat later.'
food1= 'python'
food2 = 'swamp apples'
print(mystring % (food1, food2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    print(mystring % (food1, food2))
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

command 'print(mystring % (food1, food2))' I don't understand why it says TypeError? Isn't it supposed to print as 'Fred enters the swamp and picks up a python and a swamp apple to eat later' ??

Answer (score 1):

Because you have only one `%s` in the string and you're trying to assign two values in

```
print(mystring % (food1, food2))
```

change it to:

```
print(mystring % food1)
```

and it'll print just fine

Comment: thanks! but hmmmm... so I put print(mystring %s (food1, food2)) then it says the same :(

Comment: @Anny I was referring to the `%s` in `'Fred enters the swamp and picks up %s to eat later.'` See further update in the question

Comment: got it! so I put mystring= 'Fred enters the swamp and picks up a %s and a %s to eat later.' :]

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way:

```
mystring= 'Fred enters the swamp and picks up %s to eat later.'
food1= 'python'
food2 = 'swamp apples'
print(mystring % (food1 + ' and ' + food2))
```

Output:

```
Fred enters the swamp and picks up python and swamp apples to eat later.
```

### [Demo](http://repl.it/2X2)

Comment: yay! it works! now Fred gets to eat a python and a swamp apple! but I still don't understand why the command print(mystring % (food1, food2)) says type error? basically I put on the same thing as from the book but it didn't give the same output

Comment: Its beacuse you are passing two strings while there is only one `%s` in `mystring`. What I've done is added both strings `food1` and `food2` together with an `and` between them, so now there is only one string.

Comment: got it! thanks a lot! i just found out i put the wrong variable:P it should be mystring= 'Fred enters the swamp and picks up a %s and a %s to eat later.'

Comment: Yeah! I was gonna change your `mystring`, but was kinda afraid. :P